# Making an alias for an attribute field, to be used in a django queryset

Tags: python, django

In Django, how does one give an attribute field name ***an alias*** that can be used to manipulate a queryset?

**Background:** I have a queryset where the underlying model has an auto-generating time field called "submitted_on". I want to use an alias for this time field (i.e. "date"). *Why?* Because I will concatenate this queryset with another one (with the *same* underlying model), and then `order_by('-date')`. Needless to say, this latter qset already has a 'date' attribute (attached via *annotate()*).

How do I make a 'date' alias for the former queryset? Currently, I'm doing something I feel is an inefficient hack: `qset1 = qset1.annotate(date=Max('submitted_on'))`

I'm using *Django 1.5* and *Python 2.7*.

Comment: You're going to try to concatenate QuerySets which contain two different types?

Comment: No no, same type, read my comment to Daniel's answer below.

Comment: Edited to add more clarity to the question

Comment: Have you considered just doing the sorting in python rather than sql?

Comment: The dataset isn't small. I need this for a chatting app, the qsets are made up of sentences people are saying (each person says ~700 sentences a day, there are ~1200 users per day, and growing). Would a python sort be recommended, wouldn't database sort be faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `qset1 = qset1.annotate(date=Max('submitted_on'))` is the closest I have right now. This, or using `exclude()`. I'll update if I get a better solution. Of course other experts from SO are welcome to chime in with their own answers.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could do this, it wouldn't help solve your ultimate problem. You can't use `order_by` on concatenated querysets from different models; that can't possibly work, since it is a request for the database to do an ORDER BY on the query.

Comment: Actually Daniel, both querysets will have been extracted from the **SAME** model. I simplified that out from this question, though if you want to read the gory details, head here and read my question till step (3): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137706/tricky-django-queryset-creation-concatenation-and-sorting-issue-with-complex-fo

Comment: Edited the question and added more clarity to it